# Кто на ruSO самый популярный?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, популярность

Недавно пользователь под ником [@turtles](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1881/turtles) Получил очередной [33-й](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/26/popular-question?userid=1881) (скоро и [34-й](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/28605/%d0%a3%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0)) знак [«Популярный вопрос»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/26/popular-question). И всё бы ничего, но этот пользователь задал всего 36 вопросов, то есть около 92% всех его вопросов имеют более (порой намного) 1к просмотров (около 56% – [более 2,5к](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/27/notable-question?userid=1881), около 22% – [более 10к](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/28/famous-question?userid=1881)). Мне стало интересно: «Кто на ruSO самый популярный?» Формула, думаю, ясна: кол-во вопросов с кол-вом просмотров более 1к делить на кол-во всех вопросов + кол-во всех вопросов должно быть больше 10.

Жду ответов по поводу:

- 92% – это норма?
- Результатом чего являются эти 92%?
- Что говорит о вопросе преодолённая планка в 1к просмотров?
- Результатом чего является эта преодолённая планка?

Интересно будет посмотреть ваше мнение.

Comment: _"Результатом чего являются эти 92%?"_ - нормальные заголовки + время.

Comment: Есть много незарегестрированных участников с 1 вопросом, который является популярным. У них у всех 100% по формуле

Comment: @dIm0n Ок, больше 10 вопросов должно быть

Comment: Просто очень старые вопросы. Сам участник уже давно здесь не был (с 2011).

Comment: Бессмысленный знак. Рано или поздно любой вопрос получит этот знак - даже если 999 заходов из тысячи будут следствием промаха по ссылке. Вот был бы он, скажем, "1000 просмотров **в год**" - другое дело. Правда, в такой простой формулировке вопросы могут и потерять этот знак со временем - так что лучше было бы, скажем, "1000 просмотров **за первый год**".

Comment: @Akina знаки не сбрасываются будучи получены, даже если условие их получения перестаёт выполняться в дальнейшем.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ не для всех значков это так: см., например, [эту ветку](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/301017/673852).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> 92% – это норма?

Примерно оценить популярность пользователей можно с помощью [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/). Данные в SEDE недельной давности, но для общей оценки они подходят.

Судя по [результатам запроса](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1296465) пользователь [turtles](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1881/turtles?tab=questions&sort=views) сейчас вышел на второе место по заданным критериям (33/36 ≈ 91,67%). На первом месте пока находится [arion](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2345/arion?tab=questions&sort=views) (12/13 ≈ 92,31%). Вроде бы никто из конкурентов за последнюю неделю не обошел этих двоих, хотя [strbb](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1993/strbb?tab=questions) (9/10 = 90%) очень близок к 100%.

Получается, что сейчас 92% заметно выше нормы.

Однако следует иметь ввиду, что в статистику не попадают вопросы, удаленные автором или сообществом. Неизвестно сколько «лидеры» удалили своих непопулярных вопросов. Кроме того, в статистику не попадают удаленные пользователи.

> Результатом чего являются эти 92%?

Результатом того что автор задавал много вопросов, которые привлекли к себе внимание сообщества. В случае с turtles это относительно простые (всем понятные) вопросы по Java (популярный ЯП), заданные больше девяти лет назад.

> Что говорит о вопросе преодолённая планка в 1к просмотров? Результатом чего является эта преодолённая планка?

Есть много факторов, которые влияют на количество просмотров: тема вопроса, возраст, обсуждения на мете/в чате, качество вопроса, качество заголовка, продвижение в социальных сетях и др.

Так как планка в тысячу просмотров не очень велика, а влияющих факторов очень много, то сложно что-то определенное сказать о вопросе только по этой одной метрике.

Comment: "заданные больше четырех лет назад" там вообще-то более 9 лет (у автора Последнее посещение 26 мая '11 в 0:32). Вопросы ещё с хешкода приехали и там может быть какой-то иной подсчёт просмотров ещё был.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Спасибо поправил

Comment: Можно добавить в запрос "последняя активность (вопрос/ответ/правка) была в этом году" ради интереса?) Просто из первой десятки 7 участников уже много лет даже не заходят

Comment: @dIm0n Можно, вот выборки среди тех, кто за последний год: [заходил на сайт](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1296578), опубликовал [пост](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1296581), [вопрос](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1296579) или [популярный вопрос](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1296580).

Comment: По суммарным просмотрам побеждает turtles, думаю, если в абсолютных значениях считать, он обгонит arion'а.

Comment: @return Суммарные просмотры это совсем другая история. Думаю по этому показателю догнать  [Чабановского](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky?tab=questions&sort=views) будет очень сложно.

Answer (score 3):

- 92% – это норма?

  Это очень редко и говорит скорее всего о заброшеном профиле.
- Результатом чего являются эти 92%?

  Несколько очень старых вопросов → много просмотров, а вопросов мало, получаем большой процент.
- Что говорит о вопросе преодолённая планка в 1к просмотров?

  Если очень быстро — крутой вопрос по популярной теме. Если не быстро, то в принципе ничего.
- Результатом чего является эта преодолённая планка?

  Мало вопросов и этим вопросам сто лет ;)